# Modificar archivo properties con Java sin borrar los comentarios

Tags: java, filewriter, filereader, archivo-de-propiedades

Tengo un archivo `etiquetas.config` el cual cuenta con diversas propiedades y comentarios dentro de este mismo, un ejemplo.

```
etiqueta=12
#etiqueta_comentada=23
```

Tengo en codigo las siguientes lineas

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(new FileReader("etiquetas.config"));
p.setProperty("etiqueta","21");
p.store(new FileWriter("etiquetas.config")," ");
```

Cuando ejecuto el código, en efecto, se cambia el valor de `etiqueta` pero lo que estaba con `#` (`etiqueta_comentada`) desaparece.

¿Como evitar que borre dichas lineas y que solo cambie el valor de la propiedad especificada? Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias y saludos.

Comment: si sabes inglés te recomiendo leer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565932/a-better-class-to-update-property-files/565996#565996

Comment: Gracias, hermano. Lo leeré!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La clase `java.util.Properties` en realidad no se puede usar para preservar los comentarios dentro del archivo ya que esta clase no fue diseñada para mantener el formato del archivo de propiedades. Si deseas usar la clase `Properties` puedes insertar comentarios se puede usar el segundo parámetro del método `store()`

```
  Properties p = new Properties();    
  ...
  ...   
  FileOutputStream fOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("archivo.config");
  p.setProperty("proxy", "820");
  p.store(fOutputStream, "Este es el puerto proxy usado....");
  fOutputStream.close();
```

Te sugiero usar otra opción como la realizada por @6waltf  en este enlace:

https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/53734-java-code-to-modify-properties-file-and-preserve-comments/

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * The CommentedProperties class is an extension of java.util.Properties
 * to allow retention of comment lines and blank (whitespace only) lines
 * in the properties file.
 * 
 * Written for Java version 1.4
 */
public class CommentedProperties extends java.util.Properties {

    /**
     * Use a Vector to keep a copy of lines that are a comment or 'blank'
     */
    public Vector lineData = new Vector(0, 1);

    /**
     * Use a Vector to keep a copy of lines containing a key, i.e. they are a property.
     */
    public Vector keyData = new Vector(0, 1);

    /**
     * Load properties from the specified InputStream. 
     * Overload the load method in Properties so we can keep comment and blank lines.
     * @param   inStream   The InputStream to read.
     */
    public void load(InputStream inStream) throws IOException
    {
        // The spec says that the file must be encoded using ISO-8859-1.
        BufferedReader reader =
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream, "ISO-8859-1"));
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            char c = 0;
            int pos = 0;
            // Leading whitespaces must be deleted first.
            while ( pos < line.length()
                    && Character.isWhitespace(c = line.charAt(pos))) {
                pos++;
            }

            // If empty line or begins with a comment character, save this line
            // in lineData and save a "" in keyData.
            if (    (line.length() - pos) == 0
                    || line.charAt(pos) == '#' || line.charAt(pos) == '!') {
                lineData.add(line);
                keyData.add("");
                continue;
            }

            // The characters up to the next Whitespace, ':', or '='
            // describe the key.  But look for escape sequences.
            // Try to short-circuit when there is no escape char.
            int start = pos;
            boolean needsEscape = line.indexOf('\\', pos) != -1;
            StringBuffer key = needsEscape ? new StringBuffer() : null;

            while ( pos < line.length()
                    && ! Character.isWhitespace(c = line.charAt(pos++))
                    && c != '=' && c != ':') {
                if (needsEscape && c == '\\') {
                    if (pos == line.length()) {
                        // The line continues on the next line.  If there
                        // is no next line, just treat it as a key with an
                        // empty value.
                        line = reader.readLine();
                        if (line == null)
                            line = "";
                        pos = 0;
                        while ( pos < line.length()
                                && Character.isWhitespace(c = line.charAt(pos)))
                            pos++;
                    } else {
                        c = line.charAt(pos++);
                        switch (c) {
                            case 'n':
                                key.append('\n');
                                break;
                            case 't':
                                key.append('\t');
                                break;
                            case 'r':
                                key.append('\r');
                                break;
                            case 'u':
                                if (pos + 4 <= line.length()) {
                                    char uni = (char) Integer.parseInt
                                               (line.substring(pos, pos + 4), 16);
                                    key.append(uni);
                                    pos += 4;
                                }   // else throw exception?
                                break;
                            default:
                                key.append(c);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                } else if (needsEscape)
                    key.append(c);
            }

            boolean isDelim = (c == ':' || c == '=');

            String keyString;
            if (needsEscape)
                keyString = key.toString();
            else if (isDelim || Character.isWhitespace(c))
                keyString = line.substring(start, pos - 1);
            else
                keyString = line.substring(start, pos);

            while ( pos < line.length()
                    && Character.isWhitespace(c = line.charAt(pos)))
                pos++;

            if (! isDelim && (c == ':' || c == '=')) {
                pos++;
                while ( pos < line.length()
                        && Character.isWhitespace(c = line.charAt(pos)))
                    pos++;
            }

            // Short-circuit if no escape chars found.
            if (!needsEscape) {
                put(keyString, line.substring(pos));
                // Save a "" in lineData and save this
                // keyString in keyData.
                lineData.add("");
                keyData.add(keyString);
                continue;
            }

            // Escape char found so iterate through the rest of the line.
            StringBuffer element = new StringBuffer(line.length() - pos);
            while (pos < line.length()) {
                c = line.charAt(pos++);
                if (c == '\\') {
                    if (pos == line.length()) {
                        // The line continues on the next line.
                        line = reader.readLine();

                        // We might have seen a backslash at the end of
                        // the file.  The JDK ignores the backslash in
                        // this case, so we follow for compatibility.
                        if (line == null)
                            break;

                        pos = 0;
                        while ( pos < line.length()
                                && Character.isWhitespace(c = line.charAt(pos)))
                            pos++;
                        element.ensureCapacity(line.length() - pos +
                                               element.length());
                    } else {
                        c = line.charAt(pos++);
                        switch (c) {
                            case 'n':
                                element.append('\n');
                                break;
                            case 't':
                                element.append('\t');
                                break;
                            case 'r':
                                element.append('\r');
                                break;
                            case 'u':
                                if (pos + 4 <= line.length()) {
                                    char uni = (char) Integer.parseInt
                                               (line.substring(pos, pos + 4), 16);
                                    element.append(uni);
                                    pos += 4;
                                }   // else throw exception?
                                break;
                            default:
                                element.append(c);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                } else
                    element.append(c);
            }
            put(keyString, element.toString());
            // Save a "" in lineData and save this
            // keyString in keyData.
            lineData.add("");
            keyData.add(keyString);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write the properties to the specified OutputStream.
     * 
     * Overloads the store method in Properties so we can put back comment  
     * and blank lines.                                                   
     * 
     * @param out   The OutputStream to write to.
     * @param header Ignored, here for compatability w/ Properties.
     * 
     * @exception IOException
     */
    public void store(OutputStream out, String header) throws IOException
    {
        // The spec says that the file must be encoded using ISO-8859-1.
        PrintWriter writer
        = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "ISO-8859-1"));

        // We ignore the header, because if we prepend a commented header
        // then read it back in it is now a comment, which will be saved
        // and then when we write again we would prepend Another header...

        String line;
        String key;
        StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer ();

        for (int i=0; i<lineData.size(); i++) {
            line = (String) lineData.get(i);
            key = (String) keyData.get(i);
            if (key.length() > 0) {  // This is a 'property' line, so rebuild it
                formatForOutput (key, s, true);
                s.append ('=');
                formatForOutput ((String) get(key), s, false);
                writer.println (s);
            } else {  // was a blank or comment line, so just restore it
                writer.println (line);
            }
        } 
        writer.flush ();
    }

    /**
     * Need this method from Properties because original code has StringBuilder,
     * which is an element of Java 1.5, used StringBuffer instead (because
     * this code was written for Java 1.4)
     * 
     * @param str   - the string to format
     * @param buffer - buffer to hold the string
     * @param key   - true if str the key is formatted, false if the value is formatted
     */
    private void formatForOutput(String str, StringBuffer buffer, boolean key)
    {
        if (key) {
            buffer.setLength(0);
            buffer.ensureCapacity(str.length());
        } else
            buffer.ensureCapacity(buffer.length() + str.length());
        boolean head = true;
        int size = str.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            switch (c) {
                case '\n':
                    buffer.append("\\n");
                    break;
                case '\r':
                    buffer.append("\\r");
                    break;
                case '\t':
                    buffer.append("\\t");
                    break;
                case ' ':
                    buffer.append(head ? "\\ " : " ");
                    break;
                case '\\':
                case '!':
                case '#':
                case '=':
                case ':':
                    buffer.append('\\').append(c);
                    break;
                default:
                    if (c < ' ' || c > '~') {
                        String hex = Integer.toHexString(c);
                        buffer.append("\\u0000".substring(0, 6 - hex.length()));
                        buffer.append(hex);
                    } else
                        buffer.append(c);
            }
            if (c != ' ')
                head = key;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add a Property to the end of the CommentedProperties. 
     * 
     * @param   keyString    The Property key.
     * @param   value        The value of this Property.
     */
    public void add(String keyString, String value)
    {
        put(keyString, value);
        lineData.add("");
        keyData.add(keyString);
    }

    /**
     * Add a comment or blank line or comment to the end of the CommentedProperties. 
     * 
     * @param   line The string to add to the end, make sure this is a comment
     *             or a 'whitespace' line.
     */
    public void addLine(String line)
    {
        lineData.add(line);
        keyData.add("");
    }
}
```